# Ruby 1.9.3p327 in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, heroku, ruby-1.9.3

A few days ago, [ruby 1.9.3p327](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/11/09/ruby-1-9-3-p327-is-released/) was released to handle  a [possible DoS](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/11/09/ruby19-hashdos-cve-2012-5371/) issue.

Is there a way to upgrade ruby version in Heroku? right now I have `ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]` when I put ruby "1.9.3" in my gemfile

**Update**

Heroku updated the ruby version on cedar to p327

Comment: have you tried `heroku run bundle update` ?

Comment: heroku installs latest gem on every deploy if I don't specify version.. Thats how I found out rails 3.2.9 was out.. I'll try anyway

Comment: have you tried heroku toolbelt instead of heroku gem?

Comment: I have heroku toolbelt - when I do heroku version I get heroku/toolbelt/2.33.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify a patch number in your Gemfile, you can only set the version number. Heroku will manage the patch levels so you will need to wait until they upgrade it.

See

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions